# Where is the ClickOnce user.config file location?

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

Is there a way to programmatically get the file path to the user.config file at run time for a clickonce application?

I have looked all over stack overflow, as well as general googling and can't find a method to get the path at runtime.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to preserve settings across uninstall/re-install.  Note that this is different than preserving across upgrades.  That's already working fine without any special intervention.  That's also all I can find suggestions for elsewhere on stack (and elsewhere).

Comment: Perhaps a settings import/export function would be the best option, allowing you to save or load a file in any location.

Comment: I'm heading in that direction, just thought this would be way simpler if I could just copy the file around :(.  The export/import is kind of a pain with all the variable datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering your question, but you could consider creating a subfolder in `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` to store a settings file. This maps to `%appdata%` folder in Windows Explorer.

If you create your XML or JSON settings file, then copy the contents of the file into the clipboard, you can use **Edit>Paste Special>Paste XML as classes** (or **Paste JSON as classes**) in the Visual Studio IDE to create the serialization classes automatically.

Comment: Ya, that's what I'm doing, but I'm having to manually create the file iterating through the settings, and then doing the reverse on restore.  I was really hoping to just copy the existing file around, but can't seem to find the path to it programmatically.

Comment: @Dan There is a way to get it, but I can't remember. Maybe have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application?view=netframework-4.8.1 namespace